# csh find command: how to get the upmost directory

Tags: find, csh

I'm looking for a csh command that searches directories only.
I know the name of the directory (`MY_DIR`), however I totally ignore how far below the current directory they are.

I'd like the command :

- gave no error messages in case it ended up to not accessible directories;
- gave a void string in case it didn't find the directory;
- quit the searching as soon as it found the first occurrence of the directory;
- gave priority to the upmost directories.

I thought `find` was the right command and I used it like this:

```
find . -type d ! -perm -a+r -prune -o \( -type d -o -type l \) -name MY_DIR -print -quit
```

being the directories structure as follows

```
DIR_A0/DIR_A1/DIR_A2/MY_DIR  
DIR_B0/DIR_B1/MY_DIR
```

the outcome was:

```
DIR_A0/DIR_A1/DIR_A2/MY_DIR
```

and I'd rather like to get:

```
DIR_B0/DIR_B1/MY_DIR
```

I wonder if someone could give me any advice on how to sort this thing out.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The "upmost" directory is the one with the fewest `/` characters.

[Borrowing from this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27022/33645), we can get this by piping the output to `awk`:

```
find . -name MY_DIR |\
  awk -F/ 'BEGIN { depth=100; } depth > NF { depth=NF; dir=$0; } END { print dir }'
```

Note that you'll want to remove the `-quit` option from your `find` command. AFAIK there is no way to do this with *just* find, since `find` simple finds paths as they are stored on the filesystem (which can be in any order). You'll *need* to get a full list first.